# Kernel crash at snd_ctl_find_numid+0x38/0x6c

Tags: audio, linux-kernel, alsa, tinyalsa

I am getting NULL pointer dereference occasionally at snd_ctl_find_numid+0x38/0x6c in 4.4 kernel while accessing snd_kcontrol. The issue is reproduced ocassionally. Can anybody provide any pointer in fixing the issue.
Below is the stack trace :

```
  2662.430298:   <2> PC is at snd_ctl_find_numid+0x38/0x6c
  2662.437819:   <2> LR is at snd_ctl_find_id+0x38/0xd8
  2662.662838:   <2> [<ffffff8008c4e35c>] snd_ctl_find_numid+0x38/0x6c
  2662.667513:   <2> [<ffffff8008c4e900>] snd_ctl_find_id+0x38/0xd8
  2662.673415:   <2> [<ffffff8008c4f488>] snd_ctl_elem_info+0x40/0x11c
  2662.678799:   <2> [<ffffff8008c4df5c>] snd_ctl_ioctl_compat+0x3f4/0x740
  2662.684644:   <2> [<ffffff800823477c>] compat_SyS_ioctl+0x124/0xd88
```

There is no specific usecase when the issue is observed. Sometimes issue occurs during bootup and sometimes during audio usecase.

Comment: It is better to fill bugreport on appropriate site with complete BUG message. Stack Overflow is not a support board.

Comment: Whoever forced you to stay on kernel 4.4 is whom you are paying for support. Anyway, tinyalsa sounds like an embedded device, so this is likely to be some custom driver for which nobody else will be able to help you.